# Front derailleur range suddenly has become very short

Tags: gears, derailleur, crankset

For a while when I was riding, there was a stiff feeling changing from medium to high on the crank. Yesterday it wouldn't change at all.

I checked the adjustment of the High and Low screws by following a few tutorials on line (basically, I put it into low and moved the derailleur so that the inside of it was about .5mm away from the chain and adjusting the barrel screw). This was fine, but the problem still exists: the derailleur would not move into high range.

I released the cable altogether to check the gear selecting mechanism on the handlebar its self. All's fine there too - it moved freely.

Next, I moved the derailleur by hand and discovered I still could not get the chain to move to the high sprocket. It's like the derailleur does not have the movement range to move the chain up, even if the chain is rubbing against the inner side of the derailleur.

I checked everything around the derailleur including the two adjustment screws and nothing seems to be getting in its way.

Would anyone know what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Got any photos? Would like to see the alignment of the FD.  Also you described tweaking the lower limit screw but not the high limit screw, which is the relevant one.

Comment: FD are quite exposed to the dirt thrown up by the front wheel. Cleaning and lubricating helps.

Comment: Is it a band-on or braze-on derailleur? It may have moved.

Comment: Do you have any play in the BB?  That can lead to shifting problems.

Comment: Does the shifter feel okay or does it just take a lot more pressure?  You may have something stuck in there, or the end of the inner cable may be fraying inside the shifter.

Comment: @Criggie its a band deraileur. I don't think it's moved as it's still paralell with the sprockets. The shifter feels fine when disconnected. When connected it takes a bit more pressure to shift to 2nd.

Comment: When I'm not able anymore to shift to the big crank it's when the shifting cable is worn on one of its ends and a good part of its stands are ripped (either where the cable is attached to the deraileur - i guess you would've seen that - or inside the shifter just beneath the nipple, where the cable gets bent when shifting.)

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen a couple of times. Turned out to be a little rock got in the derailleur mechanism.